# What is this 13GB download in LOL

Tags: league-of-legends

I just started the LOL client and there's this 0% bar on the top left.  I hover over it and it says like 13562 MB left... I don't really know what that is.  Could anyone please clarify that?  Thanks...

Comment: How long have you not updated? It seems it is redownloading the game then more.

Comment: I just downloaded the game yesterday.  I've never played LOL before :)

Comment: Seems a bit excessive. When you say LOL client do you mean like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bBm7KbxRZ_k/maxresdefault.jpg) and you can still log in? How big is your league folder at the moment?

Comment: Nope.  I meant, like... where the Shop is and stuff.

Comment: Well, I suppose it shows there too :) yeah

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/4wGnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LOL installer is only updated every few months. In order to install the game for the first time, you will have to install all the patches and game updates that have rolled out since the last installer update after installing the (now outdated) "base" version of the game.

This is a one-time download and you won't have to download this much ever again unless you don't update for a long time and then come back to your pre-installed game months later, at which point the client will download all the patches that have released since then, similar to what's happening now.

Comment: My LoL folder clocks in at 12.5G so that seems the good answer. Seems that over 100 champions is heavy! Just like my bronze teammates. /salt; GLHF Daneolog!

Comment: The client is there to manage the dowload of the game and the future updates. So thats why the original download is small, and then BOOM, 13G download.

Comment: Whoa... and the patches and game updates total up to 13G?!?!?! WHOA!

Comment: Can it still download even if I turn off the launcher?

Comment: my LoL folder is 13.9 GB for reference, though i have downloaded several replays, so that may be adding to it.

Comment: Hmm... the bar now says 6%, and there's 5200MB left.  It's stuck there tho! :(

Comment: @Dragonrage my folder is 18gb atm, but I have deleted ~10gb of stuff recently that didn't seem to be necessary. Riot needs to clean up their stuff.

Comment: Some of the stuff that's being downloaded is actually redundant because it's changed again in later patches in the queue, so the total size should be a little less than the amount of downloaded files. @Daneolog I also believe the launcher must be running in order to continue the download.

Comment: @Dragonrage Per default replays are stored in the Documents folder, not in the installation directory.